# How to write a python script that operates on a list of input files?

Tags: python, class, parsing, input, import

I have a program that takes an input file:

```
python subprogram.py < input.txt > out.txt
```

If I have a number of input files, how can I write a single python program runs on those inputs and produces a single output? I believe the program should run like:

```
python program.py < input_1.txt input_2.txt > out.txt
```

And the program itself should look something like:

```
from subprogram import MyClass
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myclass = MyClass()
    myclass.run()
```

Comment: There's a concept error in your shell scripting, `<` and `>` modifiers can have one file specified only, not a list of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your program accept command line parameters:

```
python program.py input_1.txt input_2.txt > out.txt
```

And you can access them like:

```
from subprogram import MyClass
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class = MyClass()
    class.run(sys.argv)
```

The way you're using is not about Python, it's about your shell. You are just redirect standart input/output to files. If you want to achieve that:

```
cat input1.txt input2.txt | python subprogram.py > out.txt
```

Comment: Or on the Windows platform:

type input_1.txt input_2.txt | python program.py > out.txt

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

> This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty. If a filename is '-', it is also replaced by sys.stdin. To specify an alternative list of filenames, pass it as the first argument to input(). A single file name is also allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Let your shell do the work for you:

```
cat input_1.txt input_2.txt | python program.py > out.text
```

The cat command will concatenate the two input files together and your python program can just read from stdin and treat them like one big file.